# How can I calculate the limit of this?

Tags: calculus

What is the limit? $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{3}{(4^n+5^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

I don't get this limit. Really, I don't know if it has limit.

Comment: Did you mean as $n$ approaches?

Comment: @Amsoti Yes, thank's

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT: $$\begin{align*}
\frac3{(4^n+5^n)^{1/n}}&=\frac3{(4^n+5^n)^{1/n}}\cdot\frac{\left((1/5)^n\right)^{1/n}}{\left((1/5)^n\right)^{1/n}}\\\\
&=\frac3{5\left(1+\left(\frac45\right)^n\right)^{1/n}}
\end{align*}$$

Can you take the limit of that last expression as $n\to\infty$?

Here’s an intuitive way to think about it. When $n$ is very large, $4^n$ is a very small fraction of $5^n$, so $\left(4^n+5^n\right)^{1/n}$ ought to be just a little more than $\left(5^n\right)^{1/n}=5$.

Comment: Note, that the question has been modified, there is no longer a "^1/n" in the enumerator.

Comment: @macydanim: Thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm sorry

Comment: @Henfe: That’s okay; it wasn’t hard to change.

Answer (score 4):

Denote the function 
$$
f(n) = \frac{3}{(4^n +5^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}
$$
Recall logarithm is a continuous function, hence denote 
$$
L(f(n)) = \log 3-\frac{\log(4^n +5^n)}{n}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} L(f(n)) = \log 3 - \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(4^n +5^n)}{n}=\log 3 - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^n \log 4 + 5^n \log 5}{4^n + 5^n} \\
=\log 3 - \log 5=\log \bigg(\frac{3}{5} \bigg)
$$
I used here L'Hospital's rule and then divided the fraction through $5^n$. 
Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=\frac{3}{5}$